# KDE Compositor "disconnecting"

Tags: nvidia, kde, compositing

When using KDE, I have the following occur after the desktop has been used heavily for several days: The compositor stops working properly for one or more applications.

An example of this would be with Chrome or KMail, which will stop responding properly to scrolling, stop updating their displays, etc. Proper functionality can be restored (at least temporarily) by turning compositing off, and then on again. (aLt-Shift-F12). This actually happened in KDE4 as well as the current KDE 5 release. It is generally most noticeable in Chrome, although that may be because it's heavily used.

The hardware in this case is an i7 laptop with an NVidia GeForce 670MX graphics card using the latest NVidia proprietary drivers.